# Possibly a bug in the markdown rendering

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, code-formatting

I was trying to using backtick escapes for entering code. If the message I am about to send has multiple lines (i.e by hitting <kbd>SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>) and then I use the backtick escape and type in an url, the url isn't escaped. The `http://` gets stripped out and it appears as a clickable url.

See below link.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13745749#13745749

The transcript shows a different story. However, in the live chat window you can see the issue.

[image]