# Markdown in Chat fails for Multi-Line Messages, a Reprise

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown

So, we are all aware of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages) post, which essentially says that messages with multiple lines are considered to be "pasted" and therefore have no markdown processing run on them.

All well and good, until it's actually [useful to have](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32401374#32401374).

I'd respectfully like to revisit this topic now, almost six years after the creation of the original post. Times have changed, and [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112524/why-didn-t-formatting-work-in-this-chat-message?noredirect=1&lq=1) [decent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215881/formatting-bug-when-newline-is-present-in-chat-message?noredirect=1&lq=1) [number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229952/markdown-not-always-working-in-chat?noredirect=1&lq=1) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133494/chat-markdown-links-dont-work-for-multiline-messages?noredirect=1&lq=1) [users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/italicisation-does-not-work-with-trailing-period-in-chat?noredirect=1&lq=1) [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213908/possibly-a-bug-in-the-markdown-rendering?noredirect=1&lq=1) [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271777/strikethrough-in-chat-does-not-work-when-message-starts-with-newline?noredirect=1&lq=1) why this exists.

The old argument about it being code seems to fall on its back now, as there's a button to format it, well, as code when multiple lines are present:

[image: A haiku about this issue]

This may have been by design back in 2010, but I really do think it's about time that this gets re-evaluated into the actual problem that it is.

Comment: It would have been great if the user was at least made aware of this.

Answer (score 8):

I think multiline markdown should definitely be implemented.

The only explanation so far is that [multiline messages are assumed to be pasted from somewhere](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56880#56880), and therefore don't need markdown.

Somewhere else I read it's [so trolls don't have that tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages/192901#comment605703_192901) - trolls don't need that tool though, they may aswell make [full screen unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136356/400261). It's the job of Room Owners and mods to stop such behavior.

If someone really pastes something from somewhere, and wants it to not markdown accidentally, there's the format button from the OP or ctrl+k to format it as code.

There are many [examples like this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14135916#14135916) where multiline markdown would be beneficial.

Comment: I agree.  It's not the absence of markdown which prevents such things from happening.