# Markdown in chat works on multi-line messages on the star board

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, chat-stars

Markdown in chat is <s>broken</s> disabled on purpose for multi-line messages, [which has been discussed more than once already on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/215040) and appears to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

However, if you star a multi-line message, Markdown actually works:

[image: screen shot of chat]

As you can see, over at the right, *Can you star this message?* appears in italics.  The behavior should probably be made consistent, so it would make sense to <s>break</s> disable Markdown on the starboard for these messages as well.

(Or, y'know, [make it work in both places](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284700/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages-a-reprise), since this is basically a bug rather than a feature on the natural language sites.)